# What's the Return of GetQueuedCompletionStatus when the I/O is cancelled via CancelIoEx?

Tags: winapi

Imagine I have a thread waiting for some I/O packets with `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`.  Another thread uses `CancelIoEx()` with `lpOverlapped == nullptr` to cancel all of the I/Os that the first thread initiated.

Will `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` return immediately, and is there an appropriate error-code with `GetLastError()`?  Or will `CancelIoEx()` prevent the I/Os from ever finishing and `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` will remain pending for further I/O?

Answer (score 4):

The answers to all of your questions are clearly stated in Microsoft's documentation.

[`CancelIoEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/cancelioex-func):

> The CancelIoEx function allows you to cancel requests in threads other than the calling thread. The CancelIo function only cancels requests in the same thread that called the CancelIo function. CancelIoEx cancels only outstanding I/O on the handle, it does not change the state of the handle; this means that you cannot rely on the state of the handle because you cannot know whether the operation was completed successfully or canceled.
>
> **If there are any pending I/O operations in progress for the specified file handle, the CancelIoEx function marks them for cancellation. Most types of operations can be canceled immediately; other operations can continue toward completion before they are actually canceled and the caller is notified.** The CancelIoEx function does not wait for all canceled operations to complete.
>
> If the file handle is associated with a completion port, an I/O completion packet is not queued to the port if a synchronous operation is successfully canceled. **For asynchronous operations still pending, the cancel operation will queue an I/O completion packet.**
>
> The operation being canceled is completed with one of three statuses; you must check the completion status to determine the completion state. The three statuses are:
>
> - The operation completed normally. This can occur **even if the operation was canceled**, because the cancel request might not have been submitted in time to cancel the operation.
> - **The operation was canceled. The GetLastError function returns ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED.**
> - The operation failed with another error. The GetLastError function returns the relevant error code.

[`GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-getqueuedcompletionstatus):

> If the GetQueuedCompletionStatus function succeeds, it dequeued a completion packet for a successful I/O operation from the completion port and has stored information in the variables pointed to by the following parameters: `lpNumberOfBytes`, `lpCompletionKey`, and `lpOverlapped`. **Upon failure (the return value is FALSE), those same parameters can contain particular value combinations as follows**:
>
> - If `*lpOverlapped` is NULL, the function did not dequeue a completion packet from the completion port. In this case, the function does not store information in the variables pointed to by the `lpNumberOfBytes` and `lpCompletionKey` parameters, and their values are indeterminate.
> - **If `*lpOverlapped` is not NULL and the function dequeues a completion packet for a failed I/O operation from the completion port, the function stores information about the failed operation in the variables pointed to by `lpNumberOfBytes`, `lpCompletionKey`, and `lpOverlapped`. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`.**

So, this means that `CancelIoEx()` will simply mark existing asynchronous operations for cancellation, and IF THE DRIVER ACTUALLY CANCELS THEM then completion statuses WILL be posted back to you indicating the operations were cancelled.

If `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` returns TRUE, that means an I/O packet with a *success* status was dequeued.

If `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` returns FALSE *AND OUTPUTS A NON-NULL `OVERLAPPED*` pointer*, that means an I/O packet with a *failure* status was dequeued, so all of the output values are valid, and you can use `GetLastError()` to get the error code for that packet.

If `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` returns FALSE *AND OUTPUTS A NULL `OVERLAPPED*` pointer*, that means `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` itself failed, so all of the output values are indeterminate and should be ignored, and you can use `GetLastError()` to get the error code for the failure.

Comment: And how do the Parameters teturned with GetQueuedCompletionStatus look like when the packed was from a cancelled I/O ? Does GetQueuedCompletionStatus still return TRUE ? Or does it return FALSE and the parameters are still valid while GetLastError() says ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED ?

Comment: @BonitaMontero - in *lpOverlapped* you got back pointer to `OVERLAPPED*` passed to original I/O request. in *lpCompletionKey* you got back what you pass in call `CreateIoCompletionPort` in *NumberOfBytes* - 0 and `GetLastError()` will be `ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED`

Comment: it return FALSE and the parameters are still valid while GetLastError() says ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED

Comment: @RbMm Where does the documentation say that ? For me it would make more sense that GetQueuedCompletionStatus returns true and *lpNumberOfBytesTransferred is zero.

Comment: @BonitaMontero I think you meant me, not RbMm,  And see the update to my answer, I quote the relevant portions of documentation.

Comment: @BonitaMontero - *If lpOverlapped is not NULL and the function dequeues a completion packet for a failed I/O operation..*  - Remy refers to the documentation, and i as can explain internal why this

Answer (score 1):

`GetQueuedCompletionStatus` return when I/O finished.  if initial code of I/O operation was `ERROR_IO_PENDING` and file bind to IOCP -when I/O finished - packet will be queued to IOCP and `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` return (for this I/O operation).

so question better be next:

Will I/O will be completed immediately if we call `CancelIoEx` on file ?

this already depend from concrete diver: are it registered cancel routine ([`IoSetCancelRoutine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-iosetcancelroutine)) on *IRP* for which he return `STATUS_PENDING`.
are this driver immediately [`IofCompleteRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-iocompleterequest) when it  `CancelRoutine` called for *IRP*. any good designed driver must do both. so if you do I/O request on say some built-in windows driver - answer - **yes** - I/O will be completed immediately.

about error code - usually (almost always) this will be `STATUS_CANCELLED` - with this status driver complete canceled *IRP*. the `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` conver error *NTSTATUS*  to win32 errors. so `STATUS_CANCELLED` will be converted to `ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED`.

so if in short

> Will *GetQueuedCompletionStatus* return immediately

yes (almost always, but depend from driver, from this api - nothing depend)

> is there an appropropate error-code ?

yes - almost always this will be `ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED`(but again depend from driver and not depend from this api)

Comment: Thanks, such kind of answers are worth gold.

Comment: @BonitaMontero - thanks, but really - all this well known info and bad english.

Comment: I think that's only known for people who deal with writing Windows device-drivers. And that are only a small portion of Windows native developers.

Comment: @BonitaMontero - i try say that from concrete api `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` here nothing depending. it return - if and when I/O completed in kernel. and final code - not from this routine - but again from kernel. also if you use asynchronous I/O - i be advice not call `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` direct and manage self thread pool - but use system thread pool - call `BindIoCompletionCallback` or `CreateThreadpoolIo` on your file. in this case part of your current code take system on self. and your task will be more simply